# AJAX Putting HTML into a div that's created in the same code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with my code, and have searched for hours what could be the fix, but with no luck. Tried many things myself, also with no luck. So here's my problem:

I have an JS function that creates a new 'Window', including all the DIV's, so everything is dynamically created. I have an AJAX request in my function, which gets data from a PHP file, and is supposed to put that data in the corresponding DIV which that same function creates. But I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

My code:

```
var proWindow = function(HEIGHT,WIDTH,TITLE,TYPE,ID){
this.max = false;
this.name = TITLE;
this.mMain = document.createElement("div");
this.mMain.className = "main";
this.appID = ID;
this.id = this.name + ID;
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/getAppContents.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {thisAppID: this.appID},
})
.done(function(result) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(result);
    var code = (result['code']);
     this.mMain.innerHTML = code;
})
.fail(function() {
    //console.log("FAILED RETRIEVING CODE FOR APPLICATION");
})
.always(function() {
    //console.log("INITIALIZING APPLICATION");
});
```

The 'this' part of the code is completely lost in the AJAX brackets, which causes the problem, AJAX doesn't know what I mean with: "this.mMain", but how am I supposed to fix that?

Thanks,
-Tristan

Comment: `console.log(this);` will show you it is the Ajax call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're losing context. Once you enter the `done` callback `this` no longer points to the outer `this` where you define your element.

You can rectify this by telling jQuery to call the callback in the outer context, via `bind()` (or jQuery's `.proxy()`):

```
.done(function(result) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(result);
    var code = (result['code']);
     this.mMain.innerHTML = code;
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Didn't realise it was that easy ;)

Comment: Always be weary of context in JS. As a general rule, asynchronous callbacks will change context by default, though you have the power to override this as shown. Please accept the answer if you deem it the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, caution with "this" key in javascript. It doesn't work as in other object programming languages (java, PHP, etc). Take into account if your code is in the global scope, i.e. a window in a browser, outer this references to the browser window, not a new window object created in your code.

On the other hand, when a ajax call is made the callback functions are executed in other scope, i.e. the jqXHR object (Deferred Object) in jQuery, so it's not the same scope on you defined or passed the callback function as function argument of  the ajax call. In general, you should think about "this" as it was a reference to the object where your function or code is executed in the runtime and that is executed in a stack context does not have to coincide with the context on the parse-time (compile time in other OOP languages).